# Is there a MATLAB function to calculate the compressibility of a data set

Tags: matlab, function, compression

Is there a function in MATLAB to test for the compressibility (.zip of .jpeg) of a set of data.  Say, if I wanted to test how many bytes are saved by compressing a 10x10 pixel area.

This is the same compressibility as is being asked here:

[How to efficiently predict if data is compressible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027022/how-to-efficiently-predict-if-data-is-compressible)

but accuracy and precision are the priorities here, and should not be sacrificed for time efficiency as they are in the that particular post.

I also don't want to actually compress these bits of information, rather I'm just seeing how well they can be compressed as a judge of their complexity.

EDIT:  It's perfectly acceptable to compress this data then run a comparison on the data sizes by the way...

Comment: Try google. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35784-sample-entropy

Comment: I've tried, thank you.  I'll keep that function in mind, but I'm specifically looking for one that detects compressibility, as in, how much space is saved by compressing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the function I was looking for:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/wavelet/examples/two-dimensional-true-compression.html

This function can return the compression ratio like I needed.