# Is there a utility for estimating a file's size after compression?

Tags: linux, compression, lossless-compression

I would like to estimate the final size of a file, files, or a directory of files after it has been compressed. I'm looking for a program or script that can estimate/calculate this.

Any ideas?

Such a tool must be accessible on the command line (for Linux/Mac). It would be most useful if it would work with all or most of the commonly-used lossless compression algorithms (`gz`, `bzip2`, `zip`, *etc.*). Bonus points if it listed the compression ratios (or of equivalent use, the resulting file size) for a variety of methods. I fully expect that such a tool would scan the file prior to producing output, but I want to avoid any actual compression, if possible.

If it matters, I'd prefer that this be general-purpose:

- It should work well for any kind of file(s), including easily-compressed ASCII text files, binary data, and everything in between. (Of course, this depends wildly on the compression algorithm/tool.)
- It should work with a variety of compression algorithms/tools

The following BASH script does what I want for *one* kind of compression algorithm, but it doesn't count (I'd like an *estimation*):

```bash
#!/bin/bash

FILES_TO_COMPRESS=`ls ./*txt`
TEMP_FILE=myData.tgz
tar -zcvf $TEMP_FILE $FILES_TO_COMPRESS
du -h $TEMP_FILE | awk '{print $1}'
rm -f $TEMP_FILE
```

I would primarily use this for larger files (larger than a gigabyte), which is why I want only the estimate, and not an actual compression.

Comment: There is no such thing as "estimating" compression for any arbitrary sequence of bytes; either you get an accurate ratio by actually performing it, or you completely guess it.

Comment: You obviously cannot estimate that (without doing the compression), because every file cannot be compressed (with a cardinality argument). Otherwise every file could be compressed multiple times to a few bytes.

Comment: That may be true, but presumably a program could perform the compression and choose not to output the file -- something like a `--dry-run` flag.

Comment: Yes, you can estimate without doing a full compression, by doing a partial compression only. See [How to efficiently predict if data is compressible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7027022/how-to-efficiently-predict-if-data-is-compressible) - but this is just the algorithm, not a readily available tool.

Answer (score 2):

You might compress into a pipe like `| wc` (you could use [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s or [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html)-s, perhaps with bash [coprocesses](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/keywords/coproc)) but you still need to compress.

<sup>(Unless you are very tight on disk space, I believe it is not worth the pain)</sup>

Notice that not every file is genuinely compressible.